# Select using Join in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, select, join

I have a question on a select using join in codeigniter:

I have 2 tables.

```
table game
id | id_team1 | id_team2
99 |    1     |    2

table team
id | team
1  | Real
2  | Barcelona
```

I want to return the team to mount a showdown: Real x Barcelona

My select this as well:

```
$this->db->select('game.*, team.team AS team_name1, team.team AS team_name2');
$this->db->from('game');   
$this->db->join('team', 'team.id = game.id_team1');
```

This way I can return the team first but not the second team or vice versa, changing the join to `jogo.id_team2`

I must return the two teams as do my join or have otherwise how can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$this->db->select('game.*, team1.team AS team_name1, team2.team AS   team_name2');
$this->db->from('game');   
$this->db->join('team as team1', 'team1.id = game.id_team1'); 
$this->db->join('team as team2', 'team2.id = game.id_team2');
```

Comment: hi bekt

exactly, easier than I imagined, but could not

Thank you very much!